# Unique sales volume by ID with MIN open date and product type

Tags: sql-server

I want to extract daily sales data where it will show an individual row for each new account opened by day.  I have tried this using the following code however, I continue getting duplicate records and not sure how to stop that from happening.

The table has the following items:

```
[AccountID]
[ID]
[AccountNumber]
[OpenDate]
[CloseDate]
[ProductType]


SELECT
[Account].[ID],
[ProdutType],
MIN ([OpenDate]) AS OpenDate,
MIN [CloseDate] AS CloseDate


FROM
[Account]

GROUP BY
[ID],
[ProductType]
```

Comment: You should not be getting duplicate rows for that query.  You should have exactly one for each ID+ProductType combination that exists (also, you'll need to handle any NULL values if they can exist in OpenDate and CloseDat).  Can you give examples of the duplicate data so that we can get a better idea of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this syntax, tweak it according your query. I need to see the results

```
With cte as
(
select          

[AccountID],
[ID],
[AccountNumber],
[OpenDate],
[CloseDate],
[ProductType],
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [AccountID] ORDER BY [OpenDate] ASC)  as [FileCount]
From                [Account]
)
select * from cte 
Group By [AccountID],
[ID],
[AccountNumber],
[OpenDate],
[CloseDate],
[ProductType]
```